# Can I version control my .bash_profile?

Tags: git, bash

In the folder tree:

```
Hard_Disk:
- Applications
- Users:
- - User-1_folder
- - User-2_folder:
- - - - .bash_history
- - - - .bash_profile
- - - - .bashrc
- - - - .gitconfig
- - - - .gitignore_global
- - - - .ssh
- - - - Applications
- - - - Desktop
- - - - ...
- - User-3_folder
- Library
- System
```

Can I version control my `.bash_profile` or any other file in the same folder as `.gitconfig`?

Is it safe to initiate a git repository in the User_folder?

Ignoring all folders and `.gitconfig` itself, just to keep some settings on track!

Comment: A. have you tried it? B. just use a (sym)link to a file in a repository, if you don't want `~/.git`. (And yeah, it is safe. What were you afraid of? It's probably not very handy, though, since most other working trees will be subdirectories of your home dir, I guess)

Comment: @sehe why are you answering on the question in comments?

Comment: @piokuc Because I didn't think my information warrants "an answer". I'm basically giving angles and asking Socratic questions. You know, almost like a conversation.

Comment: @sehe it doesn't matter if the answer is simple and straightforward or not, if it answers the question then it should be posted as an answer, not a comment

Comment: Or we could close the question as too localized or not a real question :) (anyways, feel free to write a more elaborate answer, it's okay)

Comment: @piokuc Asking someone what have they tried so far and about any preferences before you answer their question is the considerate and nice thing to do. Nothing is more annoying than answering a question before finding out there might be extra constraints. Also, people are free to either discuss in comments further details or not answer the question at all: demanding he write an answer he doesn't feel is good enough to _be_ an answer is downright silly.

Comment: @ThePhD The reason I asked was because sehe commented on my straightforward answer to the rather simple question with "This is a comment (my comment is already more elaborate than this "answer", anyways)". I deleted my answer, feeling that it'd be fair to let him put his comment as an answer. So, what happens now is we have a simple question with no answer. Dozens of people will waste their time looking at the question seeing if they can help. And this is silly, in my opinion.

Comment: @sehe I agree, I think we can close the question as not a real question.

Comment: I don't agree, the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040835/can-i-version-control-my-bash-profile/16043274#16043274) proves that my question is valid.

Comment: I can't even reply to all of your comments. @sehe A: I wouldn't ask here if I was confident about it. As I say in my question, please read carefully before commenting such things, I was in doubt I could enter in a loop of some sort, being the repo the same directory where the git configuration is. B: It would be nice from you to actually explain what sym-links are instead of being so spooky. I have been stuck at 13 points for a year, only two points left to be able to vote. Now I have only 11. This is not cool at all.

Comment: @Mauro I don't know what you're trying to imply, but _I didn't downvote here_. Recall, I was the first to respond, and I responded with the best thinking-along I could give you.

Comment: @Mauro Please take our sincere condolences for your loss. Have a package of 5 reputation on the stack. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way to go about it, although not so clean it does the job without the hassle of maintaining symlinks on each machine:

```
cd ~
git init

# Ignore everything except .bash_profile and .gitignore
echo '/*' > .gitignore
echo '!/.bash_profile' >> .gitignore
echo '!/.gitignore' >> .gitignore

# Only .bash_profile and .gitignore would be added
git add .

# Commit
git commit -m "Adding .bash_profile and .gitignore"

# Add the remote details and push the master branch into the remote
git remote add <REMOTE-NAME> <REMOTE-URL>
git push <REMOTE-NAME> master
```

One thing you got to be careful is when you're cloning this repo on another machine, `git clone` will error if the destination directory is not empty. So you could do something like this to initially set it up:

```
mkdir -p ~/temp-git-dir
cd ~
git clone <REPO-URL> ~/temp-git-dir
mv ~/temp-git-dir/.git .
rm -rf ~/temp-git-dir
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest setting up a repo in, say, `~/dotfiles` and (sym)linking into that: `ln -sv ~/dotfiles/bashrc ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @sehe - Like I mentioned, it is a personal preference. In my [dotfiles](https://github.com/Tuxdude/bootstrap) I have quite a lot of files, and I prefer not creating symlinks everytime I want to use it on a new machine. I do not see any harm in this method, other than the fact that you explicitly need to add files into your .gitignore. This is one-time compared to the fact that you need to create symlinks on every clone yourself. (May be write a script to do that ? again personal preference).